# Set UIWebView Content not to move when keyboard is shown

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, keyboard, focus, uitextfield

I've done large enough research but couldn't find answer to my question.

Suppose I have a `webView` in which I have some text fields, some of them are placed on the bottom of screen so that when keyboard appears it should hide that fields. After keyboard appears the content of `webView` slides up in order to make that fields visible. The problem is that I **DON'T** want the content to slide up.

Question is: How can I disable that feature of `webview` , or somehow make the content not scroll up.???

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to disable ALL scrolling, including the auto-scroll when you navigate between form fields, setting `webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO` doesn't quite cover everything. That stops normal tap-and-drag scrolling, but not the automatic bring-field-into-view scrolling when you navigate around a web form.

Also, watching for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` will let you prevent scrolling *when the keyboard appears*, but that will do nothing if the keyboard is already up from editing a different form field.

Here's how to prevent ALL scrolling in three simple steps:

**1) After you create the UIWebView, disable normal scrolling:**

```
myWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

**2) Then register your view controller as the scrollView's delegate:**

```
myWebView.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

(And make sure to add `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` to your class's `@interface` definition to prevent compiler warnings)

**3) Capture and undo all scroll events:**

```
// UIScrollViewDelegate method
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    scrollView.bounds = myWebView.bounds;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for interesting information but it's not actually about the question, beside that I've already solved it from Javascript.

Comment: I found that it's indeed an answer to your question.I'd prefer if you'd post your own solution.

Comment: this solution solves my case I like the phrase "bring-field-into-view scrolling"

Comment: Thanks! Worked for my purposes. One question, Richard, can you provide details on how to add UIScrollViewDelegate to the @interface?

Comment: @Garnik what is your solution by javascript? could you post your answer?

Comment: @Versus, I am really sorry, but I have posted this 7 years ago, and I don't have access to those code anymore. Also I don't remember how I solved that problem. Additionally, for some reason I used other solution later :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for me. I just scroll it down again after scrolling up.
First I catch notification `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` by adding observer to it
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];`
then implement method:

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
float kbHeight = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height]floatValue];
float kbWidth = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.width]floatValue];
BOOL keyboardIsVisible=[self UIKeyboardIsVisible];
//Check orientation and scroll down webview content by keyboard size
if(kbWidth==[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width){
    if (!keyboardIsVisible) {
        [[chatView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -kbHeight+10) animated:YES];
    } //If is landscape content scroll up is about 113 px so need to scroll down by 113
}else if (kbHeight==[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height){
    if (!keyboardIsVisible) {
        [[chatView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -113) animated:YES];
    }
}
}
```

This is not what exactly I asked but helped me to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I was looking to stop my webview from zooming in when an input field (in my case the comments section) was focused on. The entire view would zoom in automatically and put everything out of whack.
I managed to do it with this, and at the same time I got the webview to stop scrolling up and out of the way of the soft keyboard as well:

```
//Stop the webview from zooming in when the comments section is used.
UIScrollView *scrollView = [_webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
scrollView.delegate = self;

//_webView.scrollView.delegate = self; //for versions newer than iOS5.
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift5

```swift
zoom and scroll hold

class WebviewScrollViewDelegate: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var webview: WKWebView?
    
    func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?) {
        scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let webview = webview {
            scrollView.bounds = webview.bounds
            scrollView.zoomScale = webview.pageZoom
        }
    }
}

class MyWebview {
    let webviewScrollViewDelegate = WebviewScrollViewDelegate()

    webview.scrollView.delegate = webviewScrollViewDelegate
    webviewScrollViewDelegate.webview = webview
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged as Objective-C, not Swift.